# JS: Set Background on hovered items

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I have a 6 `<p>` tags on my site and want the `X` to have a different color when it's hovered:

**HTML:**

```
<p>A<span class="del">X</span></p>
<p>B<span class="del">X</span></p>
<p>C<span class="del">X</span></p>
<p>D<span class="del">X</span></p>
<p>E<span class="del">X</span></p>
<p>F<span class="del">X</span></p>
```

**JS:**

```
function func(elem) {
    'use strict';
    elem.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("del");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < spans.length; i = i + 1) {
    spans[i].onmouseover = func(spans[i]);
}
```

But with my code every `X` has a red background, even if I don't hover over anything. What do I have to change?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/ry6zbk8w/

Comment: Why not just use CSS `:hover` -- `.del:hover { background: #F00 }`? It wont interfere with any javascript actions you want to perform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.addEventListener()` I have also placed your for loop into a function called `events()`. This will be called when the page is ready.

```js
function func() {
   this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
function events(){
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("del");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < spans.length; i = i + 1) {
 spans[i].addEventListener('mouseover',func,false);
}
}
window.onload=events;
```

```html
<p>A<span class="del">X</span></p>
<p>B<span class="del">X</span></p>
<p>C<span class="del">X</span></p>
<p>D<span class="del">X</span></p>
<p>E<span class="del">X</span></p>
<p>F<span class="del">X</span></p>
```

If you have any questions, please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Yep, in combination with @codyogden 's answer it changes the bg-color when I hover over it

Comment: I didn't add the second function as it wasn't in the question. Your question is how to change it on hover, not how to change it back on mouseout. I don't appreciate people *(codyogden)* doing a copy/paste with my answer with such little changes, such a change could be posted as a comment. I'm glad this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

```
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("del");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < spans.length; i = i + 1) {
    (function(span) {
        function func(elem) {
            'use strict';
            elem.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
        span.onmouseover = func(span);
    })(spans[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `X` to return to white when the cursor leaves it, you will also need to add a second event listener for `mouseout` to each element.

```js
function func() {
   this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
function funcOut() {
   this.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
function events(){
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("del");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < spans.length; i = i + 1) {
 spans[i].addEventListener('mouseover',func,false);
    spans[i].addEventListener('mouseout',funcOut,false);
}
}
window.onload=events;
```

```html
<p>A<span class="del">X</span></p>
<p>B<span class="del">X</span></p>
<p>C<span class="del">X</span></p>
<p>D<span class="del">X</span></p>
<p>E<span class="del">X</span></p>
<p>F<span class="del">X</span></p>
```

Comment: Did you just copy/paste my answer and add in another function?

Answer (score 0):

I test your code,although I can't understand it totally,I found something may be helpful.
first,

```
spans[0].onmouseover = func(spans[0]);
```

if you code as this,the code will run immediately，not when you put your mouse on it.If you want that,you may code like this:

```
spans[0].onmouseover=function(){
     func(spans[0]);
}
```

However,if you code it in the circulation,it may lead to another mistake,for example

```
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("del");
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].onmouseover=function(){
        console.log(i);         
    }
};
```

If you run this example,you will find it doesn't output like'1,2,3..',but allways output '6'.The key is the Scope Chain in js,if you want to understand it totally,you must get the key.

At last,I give one method to the problem,this mothod use anonymous function.

```
function func(elem) {
    'use strict';
    elem.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("del");
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].onmouseover=function(num){
        return function(){
            func(spans[num]);
        };
    }(i);
};
```